# Evaluating some Limits as Riemann sums.

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I really have difficulties with Riemann Sums, especially the ones as below:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n}\right)$$
When i try to write this as a sum, it becomes $$\frac { 1 }{ n } \sum _{ k=1 }^{ 2n } \frac { 1 }{ 1+\frac { k }{ n }  } .$$   The problem is, however, to be able to compute this limit as an integral I need to have this sum from $1$ to $n$. There are some other questions like this, but if I can understand it, I will be able solve others.

Comment: Hint: Do some multiplications by $\frac{2}{2}$, then do a replacement $m=2n$.

Comment: I couldn't get it. Could you share a solution to the limit above as an answer, please?

Comment: Now set $x_k=\frac{k}{n}$ and $dx=\frac1n$ and look again.

Comment: If you look at the question, it cannot be applied here yet, because the sum is from 1 to 2n not n.

Comment: What makes this a little unusual is that your sum has 2n terms instead of n terms, so you're dividing the interval $[0,2]$ into m equal intervals and then letting $m=2n$, as suggested in the hint above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}= \sum f(x_k)\,\Delta x.
$$
where $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x}$ and $\Delta x = \dfrac 1 n$.  The variable goes from $1/n\to0$ to $(2n)/n=2$.  Hence the sum approaches
$$
\int_0^2 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx.
$$

Comment: if the integral is from 0 to 2, then Δx should be equal to (2-0)/n = 2/n?

Comment: If you divide the interval from $0$ to $2$ into $2n$ non-overlapping subintervals of equal lengths, then each subinterval has length $1/n$.

Answer (score 2):

With Eulero-Mascheroni : $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} - \log{n} \rightarrow \gamma$$ $$\sum_{k = 1}^{3n}\frac{1}{k} - \log{3n} \rightarrow \gamma$$ so $$\sum_{k = n+1}^{3n}\frac{1}{k} - \log{3n} +\log{n} \rightarrow 0$$ and then$$\sum_{k = n+1}^{3n}\frac{1}{k} \rightarrow \log{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite our expression as 
$$\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{2n}{n+k}$$
and then as 
$$\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{2n}}.$$
This is a Riemann sum for
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+x}\,dx.$$
The integral, and therefore the desired limit, is $\ln(3/2)-\ln(1/2)$, or more simply $\ln 3$.